# При изменении состояния в компоненте, происходит остановка скролла на устройства iPhone

Tags: reactjs, gsap, redux-toolkit

У меня есть компонент `MobileNavigationSlider`, его код будет ниже.
Также есть кастомный хук `useScrollFixed`, код которого тоже будет ниже.
Трудность заключается в том, что я не могу корректно определить значение остановки фиксации меню плагином ScrollTriger.
Мне удалось выяснить, что при первом рендере высота document.body = 1630px, а когда уже приходят данные с сервера, высота становится 3300px, а конец скролла у меня устанавливается на 1630px и больше не изменяется.
Пробовал в параметр `end` передавать и функнцию и что только не пробовал делать, все равно устанавливает высоту первого рендера страницы.
Буду рад любому рефакторингу кода с вашей стороны.

Это `MobileNavigationSlider`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Button from '../../UI/Button';
import Skeleton from '../Skeleton';
import {
  buttonClasses
} from '../../UI/Button';
import {
  Swiper,
  SwiperSlide
} from 'swiper/react';
import {
  FreeMode,
  Mousewheel,
  Navigation
} from 'swiper/modules';
import {
  styled
} from '@mui/material';
import {
  unstable_composeClasses as composeClasses
} from '@mui/material';
import mobileNavigationSliderClasses, {
  getMobileNavigationSliderClass
} from './mobileNavigationSliderClasses';
import {
  useMediaQuery
} from "@mui/material";
import {
  useFetchNavCategoryByCategoryIdQuery
} from '../../store/services/navCategoryApi';
import {
  useAppSelector
} from '../../hooks/redux';
import useScrollFixed from '../../hooks/useScrollFixed';
import Typography from '../../UI/Typography';


const useUtilityClasses = (ownerState) => {
  const slots = {
    root: ['root']
  }

  return composeClasses(slots, getMobileNavigationSliderClass);
}

interface IMobileNavigationSliderProps {
  component ? : React.ElementType;
  children ? : React.ReactNode;
  className ? : string;
}

const MobileNavigationButton = styled(Button)((({
  theme
}) => ({
  padding: '9px 12px',
  fontSize: '20px',
  border: 'none',
  [`&.${buttonClasses.selected}`]: {
    backgroundColor: '#1A1A1A',
    border: 'none',
    cursor: 'default',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  ...(useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up(444)) && {
    fontSize: '24px',
  }),
})));

const MobileNavigationSliderButtonNext = styled(Button)(({
  theme
}) => ({
  position: 'absolute',
  right: 0,
  top: '50%',
  transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
  '&:disabled': {
    opacity: 0,
    pointerEvents: 'none'
  },
  '&:before': {
    display: 'block',
    content: '""',
    width: '40px',
    height: '40px',
    margin: '0px',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'center center',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    transition: 'background-color 0.25s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.25s ease-in-out 0s'
  },
  '&:after': {
    display: 'block',
    width: '63px',
    height: '65px',
    content: '""',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: -1,
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0) 0%, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7) 40.25%, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.965) 86.32%, rgb(1, 1, 1) 100%)'
  },
  zIndex: 100
}));

const MobileNavigationSliderButtonPrev = styled(Button)(({
  theme
}) => ({
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  top: '50%',
  transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
  '&:disabled': {
    opacity: 0,
    pointerEvents: 'none'
  },
  '&:before': {
    display: 'block',
    content: '""',
    width: '40px',
    height: '40px',
    margin: '0px',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'center center',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    transition: 'background-color 0.25s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.25s ease-in-out 0s'
  },
  '&:after': {
    display: 'block',
    width: '63px',
    height: '65px',
    content: '""',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: -1,
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0) 0%, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7) 40.25%, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.965) 86.32%, rgb(1, 1, 1) 100%)'
  },
  zIndex: 100
}))

const MobileNavigationSlider: React.FC < IMobileNavigationSliderProps > = (props) => {
  const {
    className,
    ...other
  } = props;

  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(0);
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = React.useState(null);
  const sliderRef = React.useRef(null);

  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 767px)');
  const {
    categoryId
  } = useAppSelector(state => state.category);
  const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    isFetching
  } = useFetchNavCategoryByCategoryIdQuery(categoryId, {
    skip: categoryId === null
  });

  const handleClick = (id: number) => {
    const targetBlock = document.querySelector(`[data-category="${id}"]`);

    if (targetBlock) {
      targetBlock.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'instant'
      });
    }

    setSelected(id);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-category]`);
      let currentNavCategory: number = null;

      blocks.forEach(block => {
        const rect = block.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect.top <= 36 && rect.bottom >= 0) {
          currentNavCategory = +block.getAttribute('data-category');
        }
      });

      if (currentNavCategory !== selected) {
        setSelected(currentNavCategory);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }
  }, [selected]);

  useScrollFixed(sliderRef, {
    start: '-100px',
    end: () => document.body.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
    deps: isMobile
  });

  const ownerState = {};

  const classes = useUtilityClasses(ownerState);

  return ( <
    Swiper onSwiper = {
      setSwiper
    }
    modules = {
      [FreeMode, Mousewheel, Navigation]
    }
    navigation = {
      {
        nextEl: `.${mobileNavigationSliderClasses.nextButton}`,
        prevEl: `.${mobileNavigationSliderClasses.prevButton}`,
        disabledClass: 'SliderMenu-disabledButton',
      }
    }
    ref = {
      sliderRef
    }
    spaceBetween = {
      12
    }
    mousewheel = {
      true
    }
    slidesPerView = "auto"
    watchOverflow = {
      true
    }
    freeMode = {
      true
    }
    className = {
      clsx(classes.root, className)
    } { ...other
    } > {
      isLoading || isFetching || !data ?
      Array.from(new Array(3)).map((_, index) => ( <
        SwiperSlide key = {
          index
        }
        style = {
          {
            width: 'calc(100% / 3)'
          }
        } >
        <
        Skeleton lines = {
          1
        }
        height = {
          50
        }
        width = '100%' / >
        <
        /SwiperSlide>  
      )) : data ? .meta.pagination.total === 0 ?
        <
        SwiperSlide >
        <
        Typography > Ничего не найдено. < /Typography>  <
        /SwiperSlide> :
      data ? .data.map((item, index) => ( <
        SwiperSlide key = {
          item.id
        }
        style = {
          {
            width: 'auto'
          }
        } >
        <
        MobileNavigationButton onClick = {
          (event) => handleClick(index)
        }
        selected = {
          selected === index
        }
        variant = 'text' > {
          item.attributes.name
        } <
        /MobileNavigationButton> <
        /SwiperSlide>
      ))
    } <
    MobileNavigationSliderButtonNext onClick = {
      () => swiper.slideNext()
    }
    className = {
      mobileNavigationSliderClasses.nextButton
    }
    /> <
    MobileNavigationSliderButtonPrev onClick = {
      () => swiper.slidePrev()
    }
    className = {
      mobileNavigationSliderClasses.prevButton
    }
    /> <
    /Swiper>
  )
}

export default MobileNavigationSlider;
```

Это `useScrollFixed`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import gsap from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);


interface IScrollFixedProps {
    start?: number | string | ScrollTrigger.StartEndFunc;
    end?: string | number | ScrollTrigger.StartEndFunc;
    deps?: boolean;
    markers?: boolean;
}

const useScrollFixed = (element: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>, options: IScrollFixedProps = {}) => {
    const { 
        start='top', 
        end='bottom', 
        deps=true, 
        markers 
    } = options;    

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if(deps) {
            gsap.to(element.current, {
                scrollTrigger: {
                    trigger: element.current,
                    pin: true,
                    pinSpacing: false,
                    start,
                    end,
                    markers
                }
            })
        }

        return () => {
            const triggers = ScrollTrigger.getAll();
            triggers.forEach(trigger => {
                if(trigger.trigger === element.current) {
                    trigger.kill();
                }
            })
        }
    }, [element, start, end, deps, markers]);
};

export default useScrollFixed;
```

Comment: Также еще добавлю, что если изменяется состояние внутри компонента, например когда срабатывает `setSelected`, тогда все значения устанавливаются верно.